# Forge Viewer force on the on-screen joystick

Tags: autodesk, viewer, forge

The viewer loads a on-screen joystick for mobile devices, like phones, but not on a windows touch screen PC (e.g. surface pro) I would like to force the joystick to show, but couldn't find any documentation.

[The joystick on mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJfop.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately because that bit of the interface is not yet public we have no option but to override the mobile detector to force Viewer to adopt mobile UI.

```
Autodesk.Viewing.isMobileDevice = function(){return true} // be sure to override before Viewer is initilized...
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function(){ ...
```

Otherwise you can extend the BimWalk extension and modify the BimWalkTool constructor to always go for the mobile UI and display joystick.

```
  export function BimWalkTool(viewer, options) {

        this.viewer = viewer;
        this.options = options || {};
        this.names = ["bimwalk"];
        this.navapi = viewer.navigation;
        this.camera = this.navapi.getCamera();
        this.active = false;
        this.clock = new THREE.Clock(true);

        this.navigator = new NavigatorMobile(this): 
    };
```

I will let Engineering know it is good to have an option to toggle the joystick regardless of the browser agent and update this answer once I hear back.

Comment: Forcing the isMobileDevice to true makes other UI controls act weirdly, some of which will no longer react on mouse, and most of the time controls distinguish between touch and mouse too hard between them to work properly when switched to desktop.

Overriding the BIMWalk module helps with the problem for other UI controls. But since the tool is already blessed with a click on floor to move control, i think i could go without it on this tool.

I guess I will implement a simple 4 button camera move for now, thanks anyways.